# WCF request works from windows forms but not windows service

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, windows-authentication

My WCF service is installed as a windows service configured to use NETTCP binding. I did not do anything special other than importing the service definition, making the client and calling the function.

When I call the WCF service from a **windows forms application**, I am able to send requests normally. But when I run the same code inside a windows service running as **Local System**,
I get "*The service does not allow you to log on anonymously.*" warning and a "*socket connection aborted*" in the service trace file.

Can someone give me an idea of what else I need to take care of when making WCF requests from a windows service instead of windows forms from an authentication perspective?

Comment: What kind of security settings do you have for you WCF service (share you config)? Give a bit more description for you second WS service you are calling your WCF service from.

Answer (score 1):

From [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463274%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it looks like any WCF client that uses Local System account for the service will be treated with Anonymous NTLM. That's what solved my problem -changing the account for the service. I still don't know what account a windows forms uses, but that's ok.