# Calling a WCF service from another WCF service cause error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF service(`Service1`) that hosted in a Windows service on the `Server1`, the `Service1` used another WCF service(`Service2`) that hosted in another Windows service on `Server2`, When I call a methods of `Service1` from `WCF test client`, I get following Error:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:14:59.9850000'.
>
> Server stack trace: 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at IService1.GetHeatInstructionByOrderItemId(Int32 orderItemId)
>      at Service1Client.GetHeatInstructionByOrderItemId(Int32 orderItemId)

**but when put `Service2` on `Server1` (2 services in `Server1`) the method run without error.**

The Service2 configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBindingEndpointConfig">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MeltshopServiceLibrary.Service2">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" 
     bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingEndpointConfig"
      name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="MeltshopServiceLibrary.IService2" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="mexTcpBidingEndpoint" 
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://Server2:1531/Service2" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="MeltshopConnection" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" connectionString="Data Source=******;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****;password =****** "/>
 <add name="KosarConnection" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" connectionString="Data Source=*****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;password =*******"/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and this is `Service1` configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://Server2:1531/Service2" binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingEndpointConfig"  contract="MyServiceReference2.IService2"
     name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint3" >
      <identity>
      <dns value="Server2" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>

<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBindingEndpointConfig" closeTimeout="00:15:00" openTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Level4Service.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingEndpointConfig" name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="Level4Service.IOrderService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="mexTcpBidingEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://Server1:1531/Design_Time_Addresses/Level4Service/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ERPContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=Sqls1;Initial Catalog=ERP;User ID=sa_sysdev;Password=****" />
 </connectionStrings>
 <startup>
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
 </startup>
 <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="AutoMapper" publicKeyToken="be96cd2c38ef1005" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.1.0" newVersion="3.2.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
 </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
 </providers>
</entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [enabled tracing](http://How%20to%20turn%20on%20WCF%20tracing?) on `Service2`, and I found the following error during calling `Service2` from `Service1`.

> The service does not allow you to log on anonymously.

so using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449869/wcf-request-works-from-windows-forms-but-not-windows-service) I found the solution.

the account for My windows `Service1` was set to `LocalSystem`, so I changed it to `NetworkService` and reinstall the service and the problem solved.